# element of an $\ell$-adic Galois representation with certain eigenvalues.

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, galois-representations

Let $\mathscr{G}=Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}} / \mathbb{Q})$, $E$ an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$, and consider the $\ell$-adic representation

$$ \varphi_{\ell}: \mathscr{G} \longrightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(E[\ell]) $$

I don't see why there exists an element $c \in \varphi_{\ell}(\mathscr{G})$ with eigenvalues $\{1,-1\}$. Can someone explain me this?

Comment: This needn't be true in absolute generality. What other assumptions are you making? For example, what if $K=\mathbb{C}$, or more generally, if the $\ell$-torsion is defined over $K$?

Comment: I'm sorry I write too fast I'm working over number fields. thanks

Comment: You need more assumptions. The $\ell$-torsion may still be defined over $K$!

Comment: Reading with more attention the paper the only condition is to work with elliptic curves defined over rational.

Comment: Complex conjugation gives a conjugacy class of order 2 elements in $\mathcal{G}$. Any such element acts on $E[\ell]$ with determinant $-1$ (because of the Weil pairing). Thus its eigenvalues must be $\{ 1, -1\}$.